# Kafka connectors - Standalone mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am running file connector in standalone mode . I updated the sink connect properties file while connect is running. The changes are NOT reflected unless I restarted the connect such as

```
> bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties
> config/connect-file-source.properties
> config/connect-file-sink.properties
```

Is it possible to update the connect properties run time without restarting the connect again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible using standalone mode. This is another good reason to use distributed mode, in which you can add, update, and delete configuration whilst the worker is running using the REST interface. To create or update a connector you'd use `PUT`:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/source-file-01/config \
    -d '{
    "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "file": "/usr/share/details.txt",
    "topic": "KTest",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "name": "file_source"
}'
```

To delete it you'd use

```
curl -i -X DELETE -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/source-file-01
```

Comment: can i run the connect in distributed mode in single machine ? As i understood, standalone mode is suitable for single machine as everything runs in a single process

Comment: You can run distributed on a single machine, yes. It's generally the best way to run Kafka Connect unless you need standalone specifically (e.g. execution affinity on a given node). See https://talks.rmoff.net/DQkDj3